# How post request create to access [Authorized] by accessing [AllowAnonymous] in postman

Tags: api, asp.net-core, postman

[i created .NETCore APT according to this by using jwt](https://auth0.com/blog/securing-asp-dot-net-core-2-applications-with-jwts/)

This is the part of my TokenController

```
 [Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class TokenController : ControllerBase
{
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult CreateToken([FromBody]LoginModel login)
    {}
```

in the token controller

```
      private UserModel Authenticate(LoginModel login)
    {
        UserModel user = null;

        if (login.Username == "mario" && login.Password == "secret")
        {
            user = new UserModel { Name = "Mario Rossi", Email = "mario.rossi@domain.com" };
        }
        return user;
    }
```

And this is the part of my BooksController

```
[HttpGet, Authorize]
    public IEnumerable<Book> Get()
    {
        var currentUser = HttpContext.User;
        int userAge = 0;
        var resultBookList = new Book[] {
            new Book { Author = "Ray Bradbury", Title = "Fahrenheit 451" },
            new Book { Author = "Gabriel García Márquez", Title = "One"},
        };
      
        return resultBookList;
    }
}
```

when i send the{"username": "mario", "password": "secret"} to the api/token via postman it return me the token
but when i send it to api/books it doesn't return how to create post requst via postman to get the details of books

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are asking how shall the token be used for future web requests.  If so, you must add a header to the web request.  Example:

```
Authorization: Bearer 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
```

Postman allows adding custom headers, but for this header we can use the Postman request tab 'Authorization' to define the bearer token header.  See https://www.getpostman.com/docs/v6/postman/sending_api_requests/authorization for details how to add a bearer token header.

Comment: Oh, ok - is your question - "how do I add a bearer token header to a postman request?"

Comment: @DulangaHeshan - I have added a reference to the Postman help page regarding authorization.  You will want to review the section on bearer tokens.  It looks like the tool allows some type of authorization hierarchy - they implemented some kind of inheritance model for authorization.   Bare minimum the bearer token header must exist in the request.